# merging multiple rows into one row with different columns sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have two tables

**Account table**

```
id   |   account_no  
-----------------------    
1    | 111 
2    | 222
```

**Account details**

```
id   |   act_id (fk) | amount | created_dt_ | created_by
------------------------------------------------    
1    | 1             | 10       | 2022-10-30 | SYSTEM
2    | 1             | 100      | 2022-11-05 | user1
3    | 1             | 144      | 2022-11-10 | user2
4    | 1             | 156      | 2022-11-16 | user3
5    | 2             | 50      | 2022-11-05 | SYSTEM
6    | 2             | 51      | 2022-11-10 | user2
7    | 3             | 156      | 2022-11-16 | SYSTEM
```

I need a query to fetch only rows from account details which has at least 2 records for an account id, and merge those rows to a single row showcasing the initial amount and user who created it and the last amount and who created it, something like this

```
act_id | ini_amt | ini_dt | ini_usr  | fnl_amt | fnl_dt | fnl_usr
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1      | 10   | 2022-10-30 | SYSTEM  | 156 | 2022-11-16 | user3
2      | 50   | 2022-11-05 | SYSTEM  | 51  | 2022-11-10 | user2
```

we need only the rows with more than one records. How do i fetch that?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8 you could do it like this.

If you need also information fom account, you simle can join it

```
CREATE TABLE Account 
    (`id` int, `account_no` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Account 
    (`id`, `account_no`)
VALUES
    (1, 111),
    (2, 222)
;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE Account_details
    (`id` int, `act_id` int, `amount` int, `created_dt_` varchar(10), `created_by` varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO Account_details
    (`id`, `act_id`, `amount`, `created_dt_`, `created_by`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10, '2022-10-30', 'SYSTEM'),
    (2, 1, 100, '2022-11-05', 'user1'),
    (3, 1, 144, '2022-11-10', 'user2'),
    (4, 1, 156, '2022-11-16', 'user3'),
    (5, 2, 50, '2022-11-05', 'SYSTEM'),
    (6, 2, 51, '2022-11-10', 'user2'),
    (7, 3, 156, '2022-11-16', 'SYSTEM')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH CTE_MIN as(
 SELECT
  `act_id`, `amount`, `created_dt_`, `created_by`,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `act_id` ORDER BY `created_dt_` ASC,`id` ASC) rn
  FROM Account_details),
   CTE_MAX as(
 SELECT
  `act_id`, `amount`, `created_dt_`, `created_by`,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `act_id` ORDER BY `created_dt_` DESC,`id` DESC) rn
  FROM Account_details)
SELECT
  mi.`act_id`, mi.`amount`, mi.`created_dt_`, mi.`created_by`, ma.`amount`, ma.`created_dt_`, ma.`created_by`
  FROM
CTE_MIN mi JOIN CTE_MAX ma 
  ON mi.`act_id` = ma.`act_id` 
  AND mi.rn = ma.rn  
  AND  mi.created_dt_!=ma.created_dt_
AND ma.rn = 1 ANd mi.rn = 1
```

| act_id | amount | created_dt_ | created_by | amount | created_dt_ | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-10-30 | SYSTEM | 156 | 2022-11-16 | user3 |
| 2 | 50 | 2022-11-05 | SYSTEM | 51 | 2022-11-10 | user2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ju9P_fCh)

Comment: Add `AND  mi.created_dt_!=ma.created_dt_` so that `act_id  3` will not come into the result set as it only has one record.

Comment: Might want to ORDER BY the id of the detail table in addition to (or maybe instead of) created_dt_ to handle the possibility of more than 1 detail row for the same act_id on the same date.  Using a datetime column would handle that as well.

Comment: That is possible but unnecessary as every account is created, but the n case of multiple entries we could sort it also by I'd, when I am home I will add it to hnx

Comment: Thank you @ nbk this did work both in original MySQL DB and also Snowflake which is used as a reporting DB

Answer (score 0):

On older MySQL version which doesn't support windows functions:

```
select act_id,
       max(case when new_col='min_value' then amount     end) as ini_amt,
       max(case when new_col='min_value' then created_dt end) as ini_dt,
       max(case when new_col='min_value' then created_by end) as ini_usr,
       max(case when new_col='max_value' then amount     end) as fnl_amt,
       max(case when new_col='max_value' then created_dt end) as fnl_dt,
       max(case when new_col='max_value' then created_by end) as fnl_usr
 from (  

        select ad.id,ad.act_id,ad.amount,ad.created_dt,ad.created_by,'max_value' as new_col
        from AccountDetails ad
        inner join (select act_id,max(created_dt) as max_created_dt
                     from AccountDetails
                     group by act_id
                     having count(*) >=2
                   ) as max_val on max_val.act_id =ad.act_id and max_val.max_created_dt=ad.created_dt
    union 
        select ad1.id,ad1.act_id,ad1.amount,ad1.created_dt,ad1.created_by,'min_value'
        from AccountDetails ad1
        inner join (select act_id,min(created_dt) as min_created_dt
                     from AccountDetails
                     group by act_id
                     having count(*) >=2
                   ) as min_val on min_val.act_id =ad1.act_id and min_val.min_created_dt=ad1.created_dt
  ) as tbl
group by act_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/q2Oxq0Ay

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without CTEs, using window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select act_id,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then amount     end)  ini_amount,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then created_dt end)  ini_created_dt,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then created_by end)  ini_created_by,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then amount     end)  fnl_amount,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then created_dt end)  fnl_created_dt,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then created_by end)  fnl_created_by
from(
    select ad.*,
        row_number() over(partition by act_id order by created_dt     ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by act_id order by created_dt desc) rn_desc,
        count(*)     over(partition by act_id) cnt 
    from account_details ad
) ad
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc) and cnt > 1
group by act_id
```

In the subquery, `row_number` ranks records of the same account by ascending and descending date, while `count` checks how many records the account has.

Then, the outer query filters on accounts that have more than one record, and on the top/bottom record. We can then pivot the dataset with `group by` and conditional expressions to produce the expected result.